# Close Winword.exe in my application depending on dialog box information

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I have a third party software that starts a word process.

I have no problem finding the process with:

```
GetProcessesByName("WINWORD")
```

When the process starts a dialog box appears with different kind of informations for the user depending on if the word doc has a active macro, is write protected etc.

My question is: How can I access the header infomation of the dialog box so I can perform different actions according to the informations provided in the dialog box header?

Answer (score 1):

List windowPro = new List(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses());
foreach (Process Item in windowPro) {
    if (!(Item.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() == 0)) {

```
    if (!(Item.ProcessName == "Wuser32") & !(Item.ProcessName == "explorer")) {
        if (Item.ProcessName.Contains("WINWORD")) {
            cmbProcesses.Items.Add(Item.MainWindowTitle);

        }
    }
}
```

}

This will get any MS Word WIndow name. Hope it helps and you can take it from there. If not state EXACTLY what you want instead.